# Track links from a Facebook ad to an external site but display in my analytics dashboard

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am placing Facebook ad. The call to action in the ad is a link to a scheduling response card hosted by a third-party service -- not my domain, not my server.

I would like to track links from the Facebook ad to the 3rd party service.

Can I do so by adding my Google site tracker code to the 3rd party's response form? I know I *can* place it there. but will it record visits to that response card within my Analytics dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

> I know I can place it there.

There, being where exactly?

If they give you the ability to add your GA tracking, then you should be able to track the fb traffic to the form page.. analytics isn't tied to a domain as such, tracking and reporting are tied together via the tracking id. It should track whatever site you put it on, eg I could put your tracking code on my site and you would start to get data for my site in your GA reports. Just make sure you do not have a filter on your view that will block the applicable hostname from being tracked.

Ideally the code should be placed in the `<head></head>` or at the very bottom before the closing `</body>` tag. If the 3rd party site does not allow for the addition of javascript, then no, GA will not be able to track it.